# How to understand an $S$-valued random variable (Simple example)

Tags: probability, measure-theory

How to understand an $S$-valued random variable (in a stochastic process) and how is filtration adapted to that variable? How can you give a simple example of defined probability measure and random variables of a stochastic process etc.?

Example:
$T=\{0,1,2,3,4,...\}$

$\Omega=\{A,B,C\}$

$F=\{0,\{A\},\{B\},\{C\},\{A,B\},\{A,C\},\{B,C\},\{A,B,C\}\}$

$S=\{S1,S2\}$

$B=\{0,\{S1\},\{S2\},\{S1,S2\}\}$

$\text{Prob}(E) \in [0,1]$

Comment: The only difference between an "$S$-valued random variable" and the usual definition of a "random variable" is that the former takes values in an arbitrary measure space, as opposed to $\mathbb R$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, we might have for instance $X:\Omega\to S$ with
$$X(\omega) = \begin{cases} S_1,& \omega=A\\ S_1,& \omega=B\\ S_2,& \omega=C.\end{cases}$$
Then $\mathbb P(X=S_1)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)$ and $\mathbb P(X=S_2)=\mathbb P(C)$. To check that $X$ is measurable, we need only to compute $X^{-1}(\varnothing)$, $X^{-1}(\{S_1\})$, $X^{-1}(\{S_2\})$, $X^{-1}(\{S_1,S_2\})$.

The only filtration of interest here would be $(\{\varnothing, \{S_1,S_2\}\}, \{\varnothing, \{S_1\}, \{S_2\}, \{S_1,S_2\}\}$. In this case, it is clear that $X$ is not measurable with respect to the first $\sigma$-algebra in the filtration, as e.g. $X^{-1}(C)=S_2\notin\{\varnothing, \{S_1,S_2\}\}$.

Comment: Can you give an example of a filtration w.r.t. the stochastic process?